# What does "bash - apt-get" do differently from just "apt-get" in this command?

Tags: bash, apt-get

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
apt-get install -yq nodejs
```

We are using this command to update node. I ran just `bash -` in terminal and that just returned a new line. I have looked online and cannot find or understand what adding `bash -` to `apt-get` does in our update.sh file.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the first line downloads a script from Node servers. It is a Bash script, and Curl will print it to the standard output, so we use the pipe operator to send it to Bash. The dash (-), is the standard method of telling a program that it should read from the standard input, rather than from a file. The pipe operator works by sending the standard output of a command as the standard input to the next, so Bash will receive the script downloaded from Node servers from input and treat it like if it was a file, so it will execute it.

If you were to run the command without the `| bash -` at the end, you'd see a long Bash script written in your terminal. If you try to run `echo "echo Hi" | bash -` you'll see "Hi" in your terminal, since you're first printing `echo Hi` on screen, then sending it to Bash to execute it, which will print "Hi".

The second command does the regular installation of Node.js using your package manager.

So basically you're running a script from Node servers performing some preinstall tasks (probably adding apt keys from Node and installing dependencies) and then you're actually installing Node.js.

Comment: The line break thing may have been be my fault, sorry. OP had it on two separate lines in the source, but not formatted as code, so it was all shown on one line. I've edited it back to show two lines.

Comment: @melpomene , I copied that straight from our update.sh file. can you tell me if the code was on one line it would be written "bash - apt-get" or "bash -apt-get" ?
Also thanks Marc Sances for the quick response and thorough answer.

Comment: if you really want this as a one liner it should be: ``curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && apt-get install -yq nodejs``. The ampersands are non negotiable, otherwise, you'll get an error as bash tries to parse apt-get binary as an script.

Comment: @CurtisM If it was a straight copy, why did it have `**` before `bash` and after `apt-get`?

Comment: @MarcSances if I were to add another command after the   bash - && apt-get install -yq nodejs.  Would I  add  `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
 && apt-get install -yq nodejs | bash - && apt-get install npm@latest-version` ? could I skip the *bash -* since we're already there?

Comment: @melpomene I used the ** ** to bold the characters .

Comment: You _have_ to skip the bash - since if you don't it will try to run the output of the previous command (the script and setup of nodejs). If you just want to install another package, add it to apt-get: ``curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && apt-get install -yq nodejs npm@latest-version``, since apt-get allows to install multiple packages at once.

Comment: @MarcSances THANK YOU soo much .... That and this makes perfect sense. Happy Sunday.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Bash just ignores the dash. Piping to just `| bash` works fine.

Comment: Yes it does. Still it's common practice to use the dash, since some programs, unlike bash, do actually need it. Bash does indeed ignore the dash.